# Find columns where at least one row value is greater than 0.7 and all others are less than 0.3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.12],
    'col2': [0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1],
    'col3': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
    'col4': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
})

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  0.10   0.2   0.3   0.6
1  0.80   0.9   0.2   0.7
2  0.20   0.1   0.1   0.8
3  0.12   0.1   0.2   0.9
```

I want to find those column values where at least one row value is greater than 0.7 and all the remaining are less than 0.3. In the above snippet, the result should be:

```
['col1', 'col2']
```

I have tried the following code:

```
selected_cols = []
for col in df.columns:
    values = df[col]
    if any(values > 0.7) and all(values < 0.3):
        selected_cols.append(col)

print(selected_cols)
```

Comment: There's some syntactic ambiguity here. Is it that one value must be over 0.7 and all the rest must be below 0.3, or is it that all values must not be between 0.3 and 0.7?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
x = (df > 0.7).sum()
y = (df < 0.3).sum()
z = (x == 1) & (y == len(df) - 1)

print(z[z].index.to_list())
```

Prints:

```
['col1', 'col2']
```

Comment: And if you have more than one value > 0.7 ? `col1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 0.12]` is not selected for instance

Comment: Then use `z = (x >= 1) & (y == len(df) - x)`

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

```
[df.columns[i] for i,v in enumerate(np.transpose(df.values)) if sum(v > 0.7) == 1 and (sum(v < 0.3) == (df.shape[0] - 1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
m1 = df.gt(0.7)
m2 = df.lt(0.3)
m1count = df[m1].count()
m2count = df[m2].count()
s = m1count.ge(1) & m2count.eq(len(df)-m1count)
s[s]
```

Output:

```
col1    True
col2    True
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Method 1

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.12],
    'col2': [0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1],
    'col3': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
    'col4': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
})

# Conditions (c)
c1 = df.lt(0.3).any() # At least one value smaller than 0.3
c2 = df.gt(0.7).any() # At least one value greater than 0.7
c3 = ~(df.gt(0.3) & df.lt(0.7)).any() # No value in [0.3, 0.7]

r = df.loc[:, (c1 & c2 & c3)]

print(r)
```

##### Method 2

The following method turns column values into :

- **0** if val < 0.3
- **-len(df)** if val >= 0.3 and val <= 0.7
- **1** if val > 0.7

Thus to respect your conditions `sum` must be >= 1.

Because if only one value is between 0.3 and 0.7 `sum` can't be positive.

And `sum` is greater than 1 if at least one value is above 0.7 (values under 0.3 have no influences).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.12],
    'col2': [0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1],
    'col3': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
    'col4': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
})

r = df.loc[:, ( df.apply(lambda c:np.select([c<0.3, c>0.7], [0, 1], -len(df)).sum())
                  .ge(1)
                  )]

print(r)
```

##### Results

```
   col1  col2
0  0.10   0.2
1  0.80   0.9
2  0.20   0.1
3  0.12   0.1
```

And if you want to have only the columns names, just do :

```py
print(r.columns.tolist())
# ['col1', 'col2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has logical operations that can be applied as ufuncs. (i.e. about as fast as you can get for array operations).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.12],
    'col2': [0.2, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1],
    'col3': [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
    'col4': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
})


mask = np.logical_and(
    np.any(df > 0.7, axis=0), # at least one greater than 0.7
    np.all(
        np.logical_or(df > 0.7, df < 0.3),
        axis=0 # all values not in [0.3, 0.7]
    )
)
print(df.columns[mask])
# Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')
```

There's a syntactic ambiguity in your question though, the following mask gives the same answer for the sample dataframe , but may work for the problem you *actually* want to solve.

```
mask = np.logical_and(
    np.any(df > 0.7, axis=0), # one value > 0.7
    np.sum(df < 0.3, axis=0) == df.shape[0]-1 # all others < 0.3
)
print(df.columns[mask])
# Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean mask and walrus operator (Python>=3.8)

```
>>> df.columns[(m := df.gt(0.7)).any() & df.mask(m, 0).lt(0.3).all()].tolist()
['col1', 'col2']
```

Without walrus operator and for better understanding:

```
m1 = df.gt(0.7)
m2 = df.mask(m1, 0).lt(0.3)  # force previous values > 0.7 to be 0

df.columns[m1.any() & m2.all()].tolist()
```

The key is to force values greater than 0.7 in the first condition to be True in the second condition. Use `mask` to replace these values by 0.